# admob sticking to the top of linearlayout in android

Tags: android, admob, android-linearlayout, adview

I have got this linear layout in my xml

```
<LinearLayout   android:layout_gravity="bottom"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:background="#FFF0F000" 
android:id="@+id/questionAdLayout" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:minHeight="10dip"></LinearLayout>
```

and this is the code putting adview in it

```
adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, MY_AD_UNIT_ID );
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();
adRequest.addTestDevice(AdRequest.TEST_EMULATOR);
adView.loadAd(adRequest);
adView.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);
((LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.questionAdLayout)).addView(adView);
```

however the ad sticks to the top, instead of bottom, what am I doing wrong?

this is the full layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/questionLayout" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/stupid_bg_small">
    <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="The Stupid Test"
        android:textStyle="bold" android:textSize="20sp" android:textColor="#000000"
        android:padding="5dp" android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal|center" />
    <LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/ProgressRow" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Progress"
            android:textSize="15sp" android:textColor="#111111"
            android:layout_weight="3" android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
            android:paddingRight="10dp" />
        <ProgressBar android:id="@+id/ProgressMeter"
            style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:max="16" android:progress="-1" android:layout_weight="1"
            android:paddingRight="10dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="top|center" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="15sp" android:text="1" android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="#000000" android:id="@+id/QuestionNumber"
            android:padding="10dp" />
        <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/QuestionText"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textSize="16sp"
            android:text="A truck driver goes down a one-way street the wrong way past several police officers. How does he avoid getting caught?"
            android:textStyle="bold" android:textColor="#000000" android:padding="10dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <ListView android:id="@+id/AnswerListView" android:background="@layout/roundcorder"
        android:layout_margin="10dp" android:minHeight="40px"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice" android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:background="#FFF0F000"  android:id="@+id/questionAdLayout" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:minHeight="10dip"></LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:background="#FF00FF00"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom" android:minHeight="10dip"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What does the full layout fie look like?

Comment: can you put a snap shot of what the output will look like

Comment: got this solved adding android:layout_gravity="bottom" to the original layout